# Структура базы бумажного архива документов

Tags: sql

Есть несколько физических (здания) архивов для бумаг. Они располагаются в разных городах.
В каждом архиве несколько кабинетов. В каждом кабинете несколько шкафов (пронумерованных) c несколькими полками. Нужно составить опись расположения документов в архивах.

Посоветуйте как быть:
1. отдельные таблицы для Архивов, Комнат, Шкафов, полок.
2. отдельная таблица для Архива и отдельная таблица Комната, шкаф, полка?
3. Одна таблица для всего?

Предполагается около 150 000 - 200 000 записей в базе (т.е. документов столько).

Comment: почему нельзя сделать таблицу документ, в которой будут нужные поля : расположение, номер кабинета, номер полки ? Зачем хотите усложнить структуру данных?

Comment: думаю, что можно. вариант 4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Шкафы и полки вряд ли сильно отличаются друг от друга. Поэтому их наверное можно не нормализовать. У здания же есть адрес, привязка к городу, комната может быть расположена на определенном этаже, возможно у нее есть уровень доступа, под здания и комнаты можно завести отдельные таблицы.

В любом случае у вас будет сквозная таблица по документам, по мере ее разработки обращайте внимание на дублирующиеся строковые величины - если они появляются, выделяйте их в отдельную таблицу с расшифровкой, а в сквозной таблице оставляйте лишь числовые внешние ключи. Чем меньше по размеру будет ваша таблица - тем быстрее будут выполняться к ней запросы.

Comment: А если документы нескольких типов и у них есть как общие поля, так и характерные только для определенного типа. Как тут поступить?

Comment: @MaximK Количество типов документов заранее определено? Не будет меняться по мере эксплуатации системы? Если так, то можно вынести не совпадающие поля в отдельную таблицу по типу связи 1:1 и соединять ее при помощи LEFT JOIN, если связи нет, то просто будут возвращаться NULL-ы вместо дополнительных полей.